# Showing the order of the residue class

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Trying to study orders in number theory for my upcmoming midterms, and I found this problem my textbook which goes:

If the reduced residue classes $a$ and $b$ mod $(p)$, both have order $ 3^j$, (here $j>0$), and $p$ is prime. How would I show that of the two residue classes $ab$, and $ab^2$ , one of them has order $3^j$and the other has the order of $3^{j'}$ for some $j'< j$ ?

I would greatly appreciate help to solve this problem, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g$ be a primitive root modulo $p$. Then $p-1=3^j k$ for some
$s$ and let $h=g^k$. Both $a$ and $b$ are powers of $h$ modulo $p$; indeed
$a\equiv h^r$ and $b\equiv h^s\pmod p$ where neither $r$ nor $s$ is a multiple of $3$. Can you see where to go now?

Comment: can you check if this solution works?

Solution - since $a^(3^j) = 1 mod p, b^(3^j) = 1 modp$ , then $3^j|(p-1).$ Now let $x = a^{3^{j-1}}$, then x cannot be $1$ mod $p$, but $x^2 = 1 mod p,$ and thus we get $x = -1 mod p,$ so $a^{3^{j-1}} = -1$ mod $p.$ Similarly for $b$ we have $b^{3^{j-1}} = -1$ mod$ p$. Multiplying the above we have:

$a^{3^{j-1}} b^{3^{j-1}} = (-1)(-1)$mod $p$, but the order of ab is $3^{j'}$, and so $j <j'$ for the order of ab is $3^{j'}$